# Draw an open metric ball

Tags: real-analysis

I want to sketch the ball

$B_\frac12(1)=\{x\in X:d(x,1)\lt \frac 12\}$

for $ d:(0,1]\times (0,1] \to \Bbb R$ and $X=(0,1]$

where $d(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac1y|$

So I know that gives me  $d(x,1) =|\frac1x-1|$ and that the ball has a radius of $\frac12$ and a centre 1 but I am struggling to actually draw it so would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Have you considered taking some points to be able to make a guess as to how the ball should look like?

Comment: Further hint: $d(x, 1) = \frac{1}{x} - 1$, as $\frac{1}{x} \ge 1$.

Comment: thank you both! I will give this a go and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your metric space $(X,d)$ is isometric to the space $\bigl([1,\infty), |\cdot|\bigr)$ via the map
$$\phi:\quad X\to [1,\infty),\qquad x\mapsto y:={1\over x}\ .$$In $Y=[1,\infty)$ the open ball of radius ${1\over2}$ centered at $\phi(1)=1$ is the interval $\bigl[1,{3\over2}\bigr)$. The  inverse image in $X$ of this interval under $\phi^{-1}$ is the interval $\bigl({2\over3},1\bigr]$, and this is the answer to your question.